# Mostrar uso do Processador

Tags: php, windows, cmd

Estou tentando mostar o uso do processador do servidor com PHP. Servidor é Windows com IIS.
Já tentei usar :

```
exec("wmic /node:localhost path Win32_Processor where DeviceID='CPU0' get LoadPercentage", $out);

exec("wmic cpu get loadpercentage", $out);
```

E mais algumas formas, mas sempre retorna vazio. Alguém sabe se precisa de alguma permissão especial pra fazer isso, ou tem alguma outra ideia ?

Comment: Estou trabalhando de uma máquila linux e não posso testar mas tente isso ai e me diga o resultado: `$command ="C:\\wmic cpu get loadpercentage";
echo shell_exec($command); ` Ou com esse echo `echo  shell_exec("$command 2>&1 ; echo $?" );`

Comment: @zwitterion retornou a mensagem ''C:\wmic' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.'

Comment: removi o C:\\ do comando ai ele reconheceu, mas ainda assim veio vazio.

Comment: encontrei um erro tbm

Comment: tenta o comando assim `$command ="C:\\wmic^ cpu^ get^ loadpercentage"; `

Comment: retornou vazio também, mas eu testei em outra maquina e funcionou, é alguma coisa que falta ativar no servidor.

Comment: ele retorna isso LoadPercentage mas a porcentagem mesmo não mostra.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### phpSysInfo

Uma opção é usar o [phpSysInfo](http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/)

> **Descrição**
>   phpSysInfo é um script que mostra informações sobre seu sistema.
>   <sub>Fonte: em tradução livre — [phpSysInfo](http://phpsysinfo.github.io/phpsysinfo/)</sub>

Além de mostrar o uso do CPU, mostra até mais do que você precisa, como:

- Memória
- Ethernet
- [...] (deixei o link do site para que você dê uma olhada)

PS.: ele não usa o `exec`, ele lê todas as informações direto pelo `/proc`.

[Exemplo](http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/phpsysinfo/index.php?disp=dynamic) do que ele pode fazer.

---

### sys_getloadavg()

Também existe o [`sys_getloadavg()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sys-getloadavg.php), que pode ser uma boa jogada.

> **Nota**
>   Esta função não é implementada na plataforma Windows

<sub>[Fonte](http://www.tonylea.com/2012/how-to-get-memory-and-cpu-usage-in-php/) — em inglês</sub>

```
function retornar_uso_cpu(){

    $uso = sys_getloadavg();
    return $uso[0];     
}
```

---

```
<p><span class="description">Server CPU Usage: </span> <span class="result"><?= retornar_uso_cpu() ?>%</span></p>
```

---

### Alternativa para Windows

Uma opção que funciona no Windows seria:

> **Nota**
>   Este método não é tão rápido, então tome cuidado na quantidade de chamadas.
>   Caso algo dê errado (ex.: não ter permissões de acesso suficiente), ele retorna **0**.

```
<?php
function get_server_load() {

        if (stristr(PHP_OS, 'win')) {

            $wmi = new COM("Winmgmts://");
            $server = $wmi->execquery("SELECT LoadPercentage FROM Win32_Processor");

            $cpu_num = 0;
            $load_total = 0;

            foreach($server as $cpu){
                $cpu_num++;
                $load_total += $cpu->loadpercentage;
            }

            $load = round($load_total/$cpu_num);

        } else {

            $sys_load = sys_getloadavg();
            $load = $sys_load[0];

        }

        return (int) $load;

    }
?>
```

Comment: Eu tinha visto esse phpSysInfo, ele mostra numero de processos, e quais estão ativos, mas não mostra porcentagem de uso do processador.

Comment: No site do php fala que `sys_getloadavg()` não funciona na plataforma Windows. Se fosse Linux provavelmente teria dado certo.

Comment: Essa ultima alternativa aparentemente funciona, mas ainda assim retorna 0, eu acho que falta alguma permissão...

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro verifique onde está o executável do wmic.

1. Vá no cmd do windows e escreva `where wmic`.
2. No meu caso eu recebi essa resposta: `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe`
3. Em seguida substitua o seu path, se diferente do meu, nesse comando: echo `shell_exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\wbem\\WMIC.exe cpu get loadpercentage");`
4. Vc terá a resposta no browser loadpercentage 19 exatamente igual à resposta na janela do terminal.
5. [Outras queries](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/02/17/useful-wmic-queries/).

Comment: Eu testei com `WMIC CPU GET NAME` e retornou o nome, mas o `loadpercentage` continua retornando vazio. Será possível o `loadpercentage` estar desabilitado ou alguma coisa assim ?

Comment: aqui no meu retornou vazio tbm. Mesmo quando rodo no terminal do windows ele vem vazio. Depois eu tentei mais vezes e ele respondeu bem. No terminal e no browser.